# Having a Syntax error in the code of Web Scraping (Python 3)?

Tags: python, html, css

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

my_url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=iphone+12&sid=tyy%2C4io&as=on&as-show=on&otracker=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_6_na_na_na&otracker1=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_6_na_na_na&as-pos=1&as-type=HISTORY&suggestionId=iphone+12%7CMobiles&requestId=71ed5a8e-4348-4fef-9af8-43b7be8c4d83'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "_13oc-S"})
#print(len(containers)) "will tell number of products on the respected page"
#print(len(containers))

#print(soup.prettify(containers[0])) "will bring the page in the organised manner"
#print(soup.prettify(containers[0]))

container=containers[0]
#print(container.div.img["alt"]) "will display the name of the respected product"
#print(container.div.img["alt"])

#price=container.findAll("div",{"class":"col col-5-12 nlI3QM"}) "will tell the price of the respect project"
price=container.findAll("div",{"class":"col col-5-12 nlI3QM"})
#print(price[0].text)

ratings=container.findAll("div",{"class":"gUuXy-"})
#print(ratings[0].text)

#Making a file
filename="products.csv"
f= open(filename, "w")

#Naming the headers
headers="Product_Name,Pricing,Ratings\n"
f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    product_name = container.div.img["alt"]

    price_container = container.findAll("div", {"class": "col col-5-12 nlI3QM"})
    price = price_container[0].text.strip()

    rating_container = container.findAll("div", {"class":"gUuXy-"})
    rating = rating_container[0].text 

    #print("product_name:" + product_name)
    #print("price:" + price)
    #print("ratings:" + rating)

    #string parsing
    trim_price = ''.join(price.split(','))
    rm_rupee = trim_price.split("&#8377")
    add_rs_price = "Rs." + rm_rupee[0]
    split_price = add_rs_price.split('E')
    final_price = split_price[0]

    split_rating = rating.split(" ")
    final_rating = split_rating[0]

    print(product_name.replace(",", "|") + "," + final_price + "," + final_rating + "\n")
    f.write(product_name.replace(",", "|") + "," + final_price + "," + final_rating + "\n")

f.close()
```

`f.write(product_name.replace(",", "|") + "," + final_price + "," + final_rating + "\n")`

Having a syntax error in this specific line ,
I want to make a .CSV file but the products are not coming in the respected file.
The Syntax error is -:
*Exception has occurred: UnicodeEncodeError
'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20b9' in position 35: character maps to 
File "D:\Visual Code Folder\Python\Scraping_Flipkart.py", line 61, in 
f.write(product_name.replace(",", "|") + "," + final_price + "," + final_rating + "\n")*

Comment: Show us the full original error message!

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).    We need *minimal* code, not a 50-line program dump.  Include the entire error message.

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.  Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
f= open(filename, "w")
```

with this

```
import io
f = io.open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8")
```

Using io gives you backward compatibility with Python 2.

If you only need to support Python 3 you can use the builtin open function instead:

```
with open(fname, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(html)
```

Comment: How is this going to fix a SyntaxError?

Comment: While opening file you have to encode it using encoding="utf-8".
For Linux platform no need to do it but for Windows platform you have to use it.